# Using dictionary to select function to run

Tags: python

I am trying to use a dictionary to select what function to run depending on what the user enter. Meaning if user enter "A", function_a will run, if user enter "B", function_b will run. I've setup the dictionary, but the problem I am running into is that all of the different entries and its functions are being executed. Am I using the dictionary function wrong or did I make an mistake? I'm still pretty new to python, so I might be making some really rookie mistakes.

I've tried moving the dictionary to outside the function, but it didn't seem to work.

```py
    def set_race(self, race):

        race_list = {
            "Dragonborn": self.character_race.select_dragonborn(),
            "Dwarf": self.character_race.select_dwarf(),
            "Elf": self.character_race.select_elf(),
            "Gnome": self.character_race.select_gnome(),
            "Half-Elf": self.character_race.select_halfelf(),
            "Halfling": self.character_race.select_halfling(),
            "Half-Orc": self.character_race.select_halforc(),
            "Human": self.character_race.select_human(),
            "Tiefling": self.character_race.select_tiefling()
        }

        race_list[race]
```

When I ran the code, I was expecting only one of the function to be executed. as in the user might run

```py
bob.set_race("Elf")
```

and only

```py
self.character_race.select_elf()
```

will be executed.
But right now, when the set_race function is called, it runs through every single line before reaching the race_list[race]. Meaning all of the different select race function are being executed.

Comment: Try to specify only the function names, without `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the functions while declaring the dict. You also forgot to call you function at the end with `()`.

Try this:

```
def set_race(self, race):

        race_list = {
            "Dragonborn": self.character_race.select_dragonborn,
            "Dwarf": self.character_race.select_dwarf,
            "Elf": self.character_race.select_elf,
            "Gnome": self.character_race.select_gnome,
            "Half-Elf": self.character_race.select_halfelf,
            "Halfling": self.character_race.select_halfling,
            "Half-Orc": self.character_race.select_halforc,
            "Human": self.character_race.select_human,
            "Tiefling": self.character_race.select_tiefling
        }

        race_list[race]()
```

Comment: @DaemonPainter First, this was not the question. Second switch case is not supported by python by the way.

Comment: In your given example it is always the case that self is available.

Comment: Yeah that solved the problem! Thank you so much! Forgive me for asking but what is the difference between select_dragonborn() and select_dragonborn?

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment about self not being available was just me bring dumb and not removing the copy of the dictionary i moved somewhere else...

Comment: No worries! When you use the brackets `()`, then you are calling a function. Without the brackets its like a variable referenced to this function.

Comment: I see, thank you so much!